# Numbers and subsection spacing in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, pdfpages

[image]

Does anyone know how to separate the numbering and the subsection title? Below 11.10 works fine but here the spacing doesn´t exist... I would like to be like:

11.10. Cryptography

11.11. Physical and environmental security

And so on....

---

**Update**:
Sorry I have omitted some information. I have use the next lines to add a pdf parts to the table of contentes:

```
\includepdf[pages={-},addtotoc={%
      9,section,2,  Scope,scope_27002,
      9,section,2,  Normative references,norm_27002,
      9,section,2,  Terms and definitions,terms_27002,
      9,section,2,  Structure of this standard,struc_27002,
      10,section,2,  Information security policies,5_27002,
      12,section,2,  Organization of information security,6_27002,
      17,section,2,  Human resource security,7_27002,
      21,section,2,  Asset management,8_27002,
      27,section,2,  Access control,9_27002,
      36,section,2,  Cryptography,10_27002,
      39,section,2,  Physical and environmental security,11_27002,
      46,section,2,  Operations security,12_27002,
      57,section,2,  Communications security,13_27002},%
scale=0.7,pagecommand={}]{pdf/iso27002_2013.pdf}
```

So when I use addtotoc the spacing doesn't fit well, I have tried what you wrote before, but it didn't work :(

Is there any solution??

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I am sorry to welcome you by closing your post, but there are really a lot of questions on this topic around here. Btw.: We would have needed an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) in order to help you.

Comment: By the way, if the arguments of the `\addtotoc` instruction are section-level (rather than subsection-level) entries, you should use the number `1` instead of `2`; doing so should help the algorithm that typesets the table of contents.